# RestAssured matchers for array of strings not working as expected

Tags: rest-assured, hamcrest, serenity-bdd

When I try to match a list of strings:

```
    public void logHeaders(List<String> headers) {
        then().body("headers", Matchers.contains(headers));
    }
```

I get:

```
JSON path headers don't match.
Expected: iterable containing [<[Depth Top (m), Depth Base (m), Collector No., Sample No., Analysis Type, Age Range, Comments, Method, Sample Type]>]
  Actual: [Depth Top (m), Depth Base (m), Collector No., Sample No., Analysis Type, Age Range, Comments, Method, Sample Type]
```

Now that looks like a match to me. I have tried all sorts of variations and seems to match many questions and articles. What I am doing wrong?

JSON looks like:

```
{
    "id": 14900,
    "headers": [
        "Depth Top (m)",
        "Depth Base (m)",
        "Collector No.",
        "Sample No.",
        "Analysis Type",
        "Age Range",
        "Comments",
        "Method",
        "Sample Type"
    ], etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrgh! Comparing lists to strings. Needs to be:

```
        then().body("headers", Matchers.contains(headers.toArray(new String[headers.size()])));
```